# armazenamento de dados com Async Storage

Tags: javascript, react-native

Boa noite. meu problema é o seguinte, tenho um arquivo em js que armazena um valor de uma propriedade com o Async Storage, e quero mostrar esse valor que foi armazenado em um outro arquivo js.
Porem quando eu chamo essa função de ler o valor o react me dá um warning
"Function are not valid as a react child..."
E não mostra na tela o valor que foi digitado anteriormente

'''Arquivo que armazena'''

export default class Form extends Component{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        personName : '',
    }
}

goToHomePage = async() => {
    if(this.state.personName == ''){
       alert('Informe seu nome')
    }else{
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('name', this.state.personName)
            Actions.home()
        } catch(e){
            return e
        }
    }
}



render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                Obrigado por nos ajudar no combate a dengue ! 
            </Text> 

            <TextInput style={styles.input} 
                placeholder="Informe seu nome" 
                placeholderTextColor="#fff"
                onChangeText={(personName) => this.setState({personName})}
                value = {this.state.personName}  
            />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
                    onPress = {this.goToHomePage} 
                >

                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                        Entrar
                    </Text>

                </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

    )
}
```

}

'''Arquivo que deveria mostrar o valor'''

export default class Home extends Component{

```
getData = async() => {
    try{
        const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name')
        if(username !== null){
            return username
        }
    }catch(e){
        return e
    }

}

render(){
    return(

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
                {this.getData}
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: O maximo que eu consegui foi mostrar na tela isso : [Object object]
Aonde deveria aparecer o nome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu vi, você está executando a função que busca os dados do AsyncStorage dentro do render do componente Home. Tente recuperar o valor na hora de carregar o componente e depois passar os dados para um state que vai atualizar o componente Text. Faça a seguinte alteração:

```js
export default class Home extends Component{
 
 state = {
  usuario: ""
 }

 getData = async() => {
  var nome_usuario = "";
  try{
   const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name')
   if(username !== null){
    nome_usuario = username;
   }
  }catch(e){
   //return e
  }
  return nome_usuario;

 }
 
 async componentDidMount() {
  const nome_usuario = await this.getData();
  this.setState({ usuario: nome_usuario});
    }

 render(){
  return(

   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>
     {this.state.usuario}
    </Text>
   </View>
  )
 }
}
```